# Create random WAIT SECONDS for all commands

Tags: javascript, json, eval, imacros

I launch this iMacros code and need random wait seconds between commands, but I don't know how to make them wait randomly. So I have to insert handy below 2 lines after every commands:

```
SET rndSecWait EVAL("2 + Math.floor(Math.random()*5)")
WAIT SECONDS={{rndSecWait}}
```

Then the iMacros code will look like this:

```
VERSION BUILD=10021450
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:1.<SP>KO<SP>NI<SP>Interactive<SP>Content
FRAME F=1

SET rndSecWait EVAL("2 + Math.floor(Math.random()*5)")
WAIT SECONDS={{rndSecWait}}

TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Slide<SP>9<SP>of<SP>9:<SP>Slide<SP>9.

SET rndSecWait EVAL("2 + Math.floor(Math.random()*5)")
WAIT SECONDS={{rndSecWait}}

TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:EX<SP>NO
FRAME F=0

SET rndSecWait EVAL("2 + Math.floor(Math.random()*5)")
WAIT SECONDS={{rndSecWait}}

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:RADIO FORM=ID:responseform ATTR=ID:q*:1_answer3

SET rndSecWait EVAL("2 + Math.floor(Math.random()*5)")
WAIT SECONDS={{rndSecWait}}

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:responseform ATTR=ID:q*:1_-submit

SET rndSecWait EVAL("2 + Math.floor(Math.random()*5)")
WAIT SECONDS={{rndSecWait}}

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:responseform ATTR=ID:yui_3_17_2_1_*_29
```

It runs very well but too long, and I have to copy to over 200 commands.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce one line by creating a javascript function and call where ever required.
I hope this helps

```
WAIT SECONDS={{myFunction()}}

function myFunction() {
return (2 + Math.floor(Math.random()*5)) ;           
}
```